# using input HTML tag to insert SQL data

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sybase

I have an intranet page where I'm trying to get user inputs from simple input boxes.  Upon clicking a submit button, I'd like to send that data into my `Sybase` database.  However, I'm not sure how to call the `insert into` sql snippet.  Can I call a javascript function using the "onclick" input tag?  If so, how would I construct the javascript to properly insert the data into `Sybase`?  I need the insert SQL snippet to pass variables based on the input ID since the data will be dynamic.

Unfortunately, the only thing I have at the moment are 5 input boxes, a submit button and an insert SQL command. but, no way to successfully input the data.  `Insert into` command is below:

```
insert into table1 (SiteCode, ProductCode, BeginInventory, EndInventory, InvDate) values ('||site||', '||product||', '||bi||', '||ei||', '||indate||')
```

Comment: You need to write a server side application to do this.  Examples include .net, php, java, and coldfusion.